# get an indexed object with enum as keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list of elements depending each on other, each element has a code(as enum). I want to obtain the list of depending elements of an element, and be able to use `myElements[anElementCode]`:

```
enum Code {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C',
  D = 'D',
}

function main() {
  let myElements = [
    { Code.C: [Code.A, Code.B] },
    { Code.D: [Code.B] }
  ]
  console.log(`The Elements on that depends C are: ${myElements[Code.C]}`); 
}
```

I would like to get from `myElements[Code.C]` the list `[Code.A, Code.B]`

Actually such a code does not work, but is there a workaround to make this working?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve. Could you please clarify what you expect from typescript? Try to use `const` instead of `let` and `as const` at the end assertion for your mapping data structure

Comment: `myElements` is an array and you are trying to use `bracket notation` with `string` index where it expects to be a number

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine, index should not necessarily be a number, see the mickl answer

Comment: no, `myElements` in your example is an array and in `@mickl` example it is an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining `myElements` as an array but you actually need a dictionary with square brackets to define keys dynamically, try:

```
function main() {
    let myElements = {
        [Code.C]: [Code.A, Code.B],
        [Code.D]: [Code.B]
    };
    console.log(`The Elements on that depends C are: ${myElements[Code.C]}`); 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=8&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gE2FA3gKClAglAvFAciwIBoMoAhPQi08magmOzAEUdboF800AzMCADGAFwCWcEFAgBDMSAAUASlTkANsBHSAngFENEUCIDO1dJkwBteEgB0MALoAuKNcTBbWErHe2KDsgtXGw9WZ2Dff3IuAG5yIUljOA1bNTgAcwUAAwAVAAtkfWBDEBMoSSgRPJktJAAHUARTBhkAJ2AXABIUCD0DI2M3O0cuLKUYqDQeNFl5ZSA)

Comment: impressioned that `${myElements[Code.C]}` are properly displayed in the console directly :)

Comment: just an additional qiuck question, how to test if myElements contains, say "Code.A"?

Comment: just found out `console.log("A in elements: ${Code.A in myElements}")`